# macchanger doesn't work properly + something automatially changes my MAC address

Tags: networking, network-manager

I have noticed strage macchanger/NatworkManager/Ubuntu/??? behaviour.
When I try to change the MAC address it gives a strange error. The address is changed although, but only for ~30 seconds. Then it goes back to factory defaults.

```
$ ifconfig | grep HWaddr | grep wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:3e:86:ad:38:d6
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 down                                                                                                                                                   
$ sudo macchanger --mac=BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB wlan0                                                                                                                              
Current MAC:   08:3e:86:ad:38:d6 (Hon Hai Precision Ind.Co.Ltd)
Permanent MAC: 08:3e:86:ad:38:d6 (Hon Hai Precision Ind.Co.Ltd)
[ERROR] Could not change MAC: interface up or insufficient permissions: Too many open files in system
$ sudo ifconfig wlan0 up                                                                                                                                                     
$ ifconfig | grep HWaddr | grep wlan0                                                                                                                                        
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb  
$ ifconfig | grep HWaddr | grep wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb  
$ ifconfig | grep HWaddr | grep wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb  
$ ifconfig | grep HWaddr | grep wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb  
$ ifconfig | grep HWaddr | grep wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bb:bb:bb:bb:bb:bb 
$ ifconfig | grep HWaddr | grep wlan0
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:3e:86:ad:38:d6 # after ~30 seconds
```

What might be the problem?

---

EDIT:
I solved the problem, by replacing the default wifi driver.
This link https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-907162-start-0.html was helpful.
My wifi adapter is broadcom BCM4313.

Answer (score 0):

Is network-manager running?

Does your wifi adapter allow for it's MAC to be changed?
See https://superuser.com/questions/357295/changed-mac-address-of-wireless-card-being-ignored

The error could be related to open file limit, you could try increasing it or checking it with `ulimit -a`.

Comment: my adapter allow for it's MAC ti be changed (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2087867). it works with windows, it doesn't work with Ubuntu.

My ulimits are ok

Comment: Sounds like network-manager or something is resetting it. Have you tried changing it by `ifconfig wlan0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` or in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`